# Chaining observable and promise

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to update user's profile picture with AngularFire. I use the `put` method which returns a `promise`. Inside my `promise` I use an `observable` to change the image `URL` in user's info. At the end I change the image `URL` of the picture's `DOM` element to the image `URL` in user's info. The problem is that my `promise` tries to get the user's image `URL` before my `observable` is done updating it. Is there a way to chain an `observable` to `promise` so that `promise` only continues if `observable` is complete? 
Here is my code:

**authService.ts**

```
updatePicture(profilePicture){
    //first put the pictuer in the storage
    return storageRef.put(profilePicture)
           .then(snapshot => {
               downloadURL = snapshot.downloadURL;
           })
               //this is where I use the observable to update user info
           .then(() => {
               this.getUserAuth().subscribe(userAuth => {
                   userAuth.updateProfile({
                       displayName:userAuth.displayName,
                       photoURL:downloadURL
                   })
               })
           })
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
// I want this "then" to only happen when my observable is complete.
authService.updatePicture().then(p => {
    document.querySelector('img').src = this.userAuth.photoURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the observable into a [new promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and use that in your chain of promises like this:

```
var obs = new Observable(...);
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    obs.subscribe(your_on_next, reject, resolve);
});
```

This should give you a promise that will resolve when the observer terminates.  Now you can use that promise in the chain of promises at the point you require.  Simply return it from another `then()` in that chain.

You'll need to add some extra code to get anything out of that observable that you'd need downstream in the chain.